# How to use urbandictionary API built in API function random()

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to build a simple app that will generate random words and their associated defintion from the urban dictionary api. I was thinking I could somehow scrape the website or find a database or .csv file with most of the urban dictionary words and then inject that into the api {word}.

I found their unofficial/official API online here: http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0

And more information about it here: https://pub.dev/documentation/urbandictionary/latest/urbandictionary/OfficialUrbanDictionaryClient-class.html
And here: https://pub.dev/documentation/urbandictionary/latest/urbandictionary/UrbanDictionary-class.html

Inside the second pub.dev link there appears to be a built-in function that generates a random list of words from the site. So obviously rather than having to find a database/web scrape the words this would be a much better way to create this app. Problem is I dont know how to call that function in my code.

New to APIs and here my code so far:

```
import requests
word = "all good in the hood"
response = requests.get(f"http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term={word}")
print(response.text)
```

This gives a long JSON/Dictionary in VSCODE. I think I'd be able to expand on this idea if it's possible to access that random function and just get a random word from the list.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/random`](https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/random)?

Comment: @Selcuk yeah that was it... didn't realize how easy that would be... How would I extract out the word and the definition from JSON? When I print(response.JSON()) I get back all this: ```{'list': [{'definition': 'A classic rave/club-whore term that refers to a brief nap.', 'permalink': 'http://disco-nap.urbanup.com/1087145', 'thumbs_up': 435, 'sound_urls': [], 'author': 'tfk', 'word': 'disco nap', 'defid': 1087145, 'current_vote': '', 'written_on': '2005-02-26T17:40:22.000Z', 'example': 'I [had to] [catch] a disco nap before going to the [next] party.', 'thumbs_down': 288}, {'definition':```

Comment: Please learn to [edit] for adding that much info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scraping all the words in the Urban Dictionary would take a very long time. You can get a random word from the Urban Dictionary by calling `https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/random`

Here's a function that gets a random word from the Urban Dictionary

```
def randomword():
    response = requests.get("https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/random")

    return response.text
```

In order to convert the response to JSON, you have to import JSON and do `json.loads(response.text)`. Once converted to JSON, it is basically a dictionary. Here's a code that gets the definition, word, and author of the first definition

```
data = json.loads(randomword()) #gets random and converts to JSON
firstdef = data["list"][0] #gets first definition
author = firstdef["author"] #author of definition
definition = firstdef["definition"] #definition of word
word = firstdef["word"]  #word
```

Comment: Thanks this works exactly as expected!! I was thinking of making a simple web app with dark background and light letters with a button somewhere for a random word generator. In python what do you think would be the best way to do this?

Comment: you can use flask to create a web application. Here's a good article on how to do [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

The text is in json format, so just use the json module to convert to a dictionary. I also had it just give the definition with the most thumbs

```
import json
import requests
word = "all good in the hood"
response = requests.get(f"http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term={word}")
dictionary = json.loads(response.text)['list']
most_thumbs = -1
best_definition = ""
for definition in dictionary:
    if definition['thumbs_up']>most_thumbs:
        most_thumbs = definition['thumbs_up']
        best_definition = definition['definition']
print(f"{word}: {best_definition}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the above comment, I share the method you need.

```
import requests
word = "all good in the hood"
response = requests.get(f"https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/random")

# get all list item 
for obj in response.json()['list']:
    print(obj)

# get index 0 of list
print(response.json()['list'][0])

# get index 0 - word of list
print(response.json()['list'][0]['word'])
```